# How to call a shape (2D or 3D) that has no dents in it?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Is there a name for a shape that has no dents in it?

The shape can exist in 2D or 3D space. It is best demonstrated with a picture:

[image]

On the left is a shape that has no dents in it, and on the right a shape with a dent.

Mathematically, a shape without dents is defined that for every pair of points on the circumference of the shape, the line connecting them will be entirely inside the shape (or on its circumference).

Comment: We call this property **convexity**, and we can define it just as well for shapes in higher dimensions (and actually in even more settings).

Comment: Is convexity the lack of dents, or the existence of them?

Comment: Lack thereof. ${}$

Comment: Convexity is the "lack of dents"---more formally it's defined more or less how you described the property: A subset $S$ of Euclidean space is **convex** if for any two points in $S$ the line segment connecting the two points is a subset of $S$.

Comment: Convexity of a set $A$ means that for any two points $a$ and $b$ in $A$, every point on the line segment joining $a$ and $b$ is in $A$. The set need not have a boundary. For example the open disk $x^2+y^2\lt 1$ is convex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the property (of having no "dents") is *convexity**. It can be important in some circumstances when working with polygons, but we can actually make sense of the term for general subsets of Euclidean space (of any dimension, including the usual 2- and 3-dimensional spaces you mention), using more or less the definition you gave yourself:

A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is **convex** if for every point $x, y \in S$ the line segment connecting $x$ and $y$ is itself a subset of $S$.

You'll see that this isn't phrased quite as in your definition, which only checks pairs of points on the boundary of the shape, but it's easy to show that the two are actually equivalent when the subset $S$ is bounded (roughly speaking, doesn't "extend to infinity").

(In fact, we can make sense of convexity in more general settings too, but I won't say anything about that except that it turns out to be critically important in several places.)